# Demonstrate that a matrix has no LU factorization

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Have to show that

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
has no LU factorization.

<s>It seems trivial just to say that this cannot have an LU decomposition because it is a lower triangular matrix already.</s>

What is a more formal way of suggesting that this cannot be furth decomposed into LU?

Comment: Lower triangle usually means lower left triangular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your matrix is not lower triangular. If it were, then taking $U$ to be the identity matrix would give you an LU decomposition.

What happens here is that your matrix is non-singular, and its $1,1$ entry is zero. If you write it as $LU$ with $L$ lower triangular and $U$ upper triangular, then $A_{11}=L_{11}U_{11}$. So either $L_{11}=0$ or $U_{11}=0$, and this would made the corresponding matrix singular, and so $A$ would be singular, a contradiction.

Comment: Why can't I switch the two rows in A? The equation we were given in our lecture was PA = LU, where P is a permutation matrix. So i can switch the two rows in A with that, and then have L=Id, and R=PA, can't I?

Comment: You can, if you want. It is a different problem than the one asked here, though. If you want $PA=LU$, it works for every choice of $A$, whether singular or non-singular.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}$ has an $LU$ decomposition.

Then $A=LU$ for some lower triangular matrix $L$ and upper triangular matrix $U$.

Let $L= \pmatrix{ l_{11} & 0 \\ l_{21} & l_{22}}$ and $U = \pmatrix{ u_{11} & u_{12} \\ 0 & u_{22}}$

By matrix multiplication, we conclude the following:

$a_{11} = l_{11} \cdot u_{11} = 0$, so it must be either $l_{11}=0$ or $u_{11}=0$.

Suppose $l_{11}=0$. Since $a_{12} = l_{11} \cdot u_{12}$ this would imply $a_{12} = 0 \neq 1$, a contradiction.

Suppose $u_{11}=0$. Since $a_{21} = l_{21} \cdot u_{11}$ this would imply $a_{21} = 0 \neq 1$, also a contradiction.

So we conclude that $A$ cannot have an $LU$ decomposition. $\square$

Comment: How can this generalize?

Comment: @ryan : Every LU factorization of the full matrix can be cut down to an LU factorization of the upper left quadratic submatrix. So if an LU factorization is not possible for the sub-matrix (any of them) it is not possible for the full matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that an argument based on the nature of the LU decomposition suffices. A constructive argument would be, that a step in the LU decomposition algorithm can not be performed - division by zero, e.g. $l_{i,1}=\frac{ a_{i,1} }{a_{1,1} }$ where here $i=2$. Hence the simple LU decomposition is not possible.
Though LU with partial pivoting is still possible (trivial).