# Showing $LU$ is impossible...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Show that $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=LU$ is impossible where $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular.

Comment: What does a lower and upper triangular matrix look like? Use variables, multiply, check consistency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Demonstrate that a matrix has no LU factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659034/demonstrate-that-a-matrix-has-no-lu-factorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ax & ay \\ bx & by+cz \end{bmatrix}.$$
From $bx = ay = 1$ it follows that $a,x\ne 0$ but this contradicts $ax = 0$.